# :hover links not working

Tags: css, tags, anchor

I am developing a website from scratch and I am having some trouble with my anchor tags. 
I use the following css class in order to change the nav links state:

```
.nav-color:hover a{
    color: #e67d20;
}
```

But insted of changing the link which the mouse is over, it changes all three nav links together. I hope you can help me, this never happened to me before!

Here is the sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/yYnGK/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```css
.nav-color a:hover{
    color: #e67d20;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yYnGK/2/)

Visit [*Pseudo Classes CSS Selctors*](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3ahover)